# Date format using `\advdate` package

Tags: advdate

I tried `\renewcommand{\today}{\the\day/\the\month}` intendint to change the date format to dd/mm. It didn't work.

I searched for similar questions, but found no answer to my case (I'm using exclusively the `\advdate` package). Is there any work around?

Thank you!

### Edit

As required, here it goes a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{advdate}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\ThisDay{1}
\ThisMonth{2}
\ThisYear{2019}

\newcommand{\nextevent}{%
    \section*{\today}
    \vspace{-3mm}
    \AdvanceDate[15]
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \Large
    My schedule
\end{center}

\nextevent
I will travel.

\nextevent
I will come back.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Hi, @samcarter. I just edited the question to answer your request. Observe that the date is in the format *1 de fevereiro de 2019*, while I would like it to display *01/02*. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry to bother you here, but you didn't have to delete your question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/477713/35864. Marking questions as duplicates instead of just deleting them helps the community because duplicate questions remain searchable and therefore can serve as signposts with slightly different search terms, which makes stuff overall easier to search for. It just doesn't make a whole lot of sense to add a separate answer if there is a perfectly good answer elsewhere already.

Comment: Hi, @moewe, thank you for this tip. I still new to the community and I thought that keeping duplicate question would make me less contributive. So I deleted it because I want the very contrary and then help {TEX} improve. You don't bother, and I just have to thank you!

Comment: Some people think that duplicate closures look bad (presumably because *other* closures are indication of a unsuitable or lower-quality question). I happen to disagree and think that duplicates are a fundamental part of the working of this site. There should be no stigma attached to having one's question closed as a duplicate. As I said good duplicate questions (with an accurate description of the problem, good tags, etc.) can be extremely beneficial to the community.

Comment: I now understand and agree with you. I will not delete duplicate posts any more. Thank you for the help, @moewe :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick hack: instead of using `\today` build the date yourself

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{advdate}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\ThisDay{1}
\ThisMonth{2}
\ThisYear{2019}

\newcommand{\nextevent}{%
    \section*{%
        \ifnum \number\day < 10 0\fi \number\day
        /%
        \ifnum \number\month < 10 0\fi \number\month
    }
    \vspace{-3mm}
    \AdvanceDate[15]
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \Large
    My schedule
\end{center}

\nextevent
I will travel.

\nextevent
I will come back.

\end{document}
```

[image]